# Can a user modify values stored in NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore?

Tags: ios, icloud, icloud-api, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

I am using `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` to store a dictionary of users data on iCloud (gems, username etc).

Gems can be purchased in the app as a consumable IAP, and the total number of gems the user has is then stored in `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`. If a user is able to modify this then that would have a large impact on my business model where a user could bypass the IAP and modify this value directly.

So the question is how secure is `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` and is it suitable for my scenario? I've found a few relevant questions on SO but no definitive answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping IAP and other critical app data on NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore is a flawed business model.

Users cannot modify NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore directly but they can delete it. Or they can turn Documents & Data option off for your app. Even they might be **not using iCloud** on their iDevice in the first place.

You need to use your own server for this.

Comment: Thank you. So to clarify, NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore relies on the user having Documents & Data turned on? Can you also tell me the steps to take to delete it?

Comment: Resetting iCloud Documents & Data http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5824 (Though it says "These steps won't delete your documents and data". I never noticed it before.)